# How to remove background of <tooltip>

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am having a `<tooltip>`. Inside that, I am having a `<button>`. But this shows a background around button. How to remove it? I want just the button to appear as if it is just a standalone button floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<tooltip>` element doesn't have a predefined background, at least not in the default Windows theme. Instead it seems to use the default background defined by the operating system. You can disable this behavior by changing [`-moz-appearance` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance). Setting background as well won't harm, other themes might defined it:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
background: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to make tooltip's background transparent.

Comment: I tried background:transparent !important; But it didn't worked.