# how to format the border radius in groupbox XUL

Tags: css, xul

I have one groupbox control in xul:

```
<xul:groupbox id="gbLogin" style="margin-top:50px;-moz-border-radius:10px;">
<xul:caption label="Log in" style="color:red;font-size:20px;" />
<xul:hbox style="margin-left:340px;margin-right:280px;">
</xul:hbox>
</xul:groupbox>
```

but the -moz-border-radius property not working in XUL application. It is taking default border-radius.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Firefox no longer needs it's browser prefix to run.  My guess would be that because of this it is using the default border-radius value assuming you have firefox 4 or newer. - http://css-tricks.com/do-we-need-box-shadow-prefixes/

Comment: Both border-radius and -moz-border-radius not working for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove background of <tooltip>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690860/how-to-remove-background-of-tooltip)

Comment: Thanks same issue which you have suggested. Now working fine.